# Visual Studio IntelliSense options is missing for JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-javascript-intellisense?view=vs-2022) I should be able to access the JavaScript IntelliSense "References" options by choosing Tools > Options on the menu bar, and then expanding Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > IntelliSense. But it is completely missing there and I have just "General" section. Any solutions?

[image]

Comment: A dumb question, have you installed Typescript support in VS installer?

Comment: @Dimava unrelated, but yes I've installed version 4.9.3

Answer (score 1):

This might be a problem in visual studio, I filed this issue on DC. You can follow [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Text-Editor--JavaScriptTypeScript--I/10204360?port=1025&fsid=12e9dbc5-5c60-4d00-bf6e-56dfe4d8bbee).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope they do something about it.